Book series involving an intersystem war and nanite technology
I read this series of books when I was a child. I was ~10 years old at the time so this was around 2011/2012. They were on the Barnes and Noble Nook for me, so I have no way of finding them again (that nook has long since been lost and the associated email closed).
What I do remember is that it revolved around a large fleet of star ships that were fighting a war.
At some point they traversed through portals to enter another system, where they got stuck on the other side and encountered nanite technology, which became deeply intertwined with their own systems. The main character switched from being the original Commander to his son upon returning to our solar system.

I POSTED THIS AND THEN IMMEDIATELY FOUND THE SERIES AHAHAHA IT'S BEEN YEARS
For anyone interested by my (admittedly terrible) description, it's B.V. Larson's Star Force series. Summary from the first book, Swarm

Earth arms marines with alien technology and builds its first battle fleet!
Kyle Riggs is snatched by an alien spacecraft sometime after midnight. The ship is testing everyone it catches and murdering the weak. The good news is that Kyle keeps passing tests and staying alive. The bad news is the aliens who sent this ship are the nicest ones out there....
SWARM is the story of Earth's annexation by an alien empire. Long considered a primitive people on a backwater planet, humanity finds itself in the middle of a war, and faced with extinction. SWARM is an 88,000 word novel of science fiction by bestselling author B. V. Larson.


Very glad that you’ve found what you were looking for. Please do stick around to mark your answer as accepted, it should be available to accept In the next 48 hours. Welcome to the site.
